# Highlight differences between two strings

Tags: oracle, plsql, string-comparison, oracle11gr2

If I have two longish strings, VARCHAR2s, is there a simple method or algorithm I can copy or port to PL/SQL to compare them, inserting markup (i.e. so that when rendered in a web page the differences will be highlighted).

For example:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(
    markup_differences
         (in_old     => 'Hello world, this is your captain speaking.'
         ,in_new     => 'Hello WORLD, this is not your captain.'
         ,in_preins  => '<ins>'
         ,in_postins => '</ins>'
         ,in_predel  => '<del>'
         ,in_postdel => '</del>'
         ));
END;
```

Expected output:

```
Hello <del>world</del><ins>WORLD</ins>, this is <ins>not</ins> your captain
<del>speaking</del>.
```

Notice that this shows that "world' was changed to "WORLD", that "not" was inserted, and that "speaking" was removed.

Background: My intention is to compare two mostly-similar HTML fragments, and mark them up with highlights for display in a browser. Performance will not be a priority. This is for a throwaway app, so I'm not after a perfect solution. Even if something gets me part of the way there will be better than nothing - and I haven't promised anything to the client yet :)

Alternatively, a simple solution in Javascript that I can easily incorporate in my Apex application would be acceptable.

Comment: Are you only interested in whole words or in parts of words as well?

Comment: If JS is acceptable [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) piece of code seem to be doing good.

Comment: @Ben: might be words, might be parts of words.

Comment: @WojtusJ: looks interesting, looking through it now. I'm not very experienced with JS so might take me some time to work out how to use it.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp, the library uses _Myer's diff algorithm_, also there is a link to detail, you can try to implement it. Also - which might be easier - the description states there is a Java version. You can create a Java Package in pl/sql, and use it within your code.

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems that code allows you to get a list of diffs between two strings, but it doesn't mark up the original string (including the unchanged bits).

Comment: You can than for example wrap it in your own simple Java Class, in which you can transform the list into string with markup and port that class into Oracle Java Package.

Comment: I haven't pursued this further since I've found a simpler alternative, doing the comparison at an earlier stage prior to generating the HTML. Thanks everyone for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a really simple js-diff algorithm on John Resigs Blog: http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/

Maybe that helps.

Comment: Looks a bit simpler, might be able to port this to PL/SQL if I can learn JS.

Comment: giving this the thumbs up because I think it would have been most likely to help me achieve this, if I needed to.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp - How far did you get with this? It seems like somebody has made this approach work [in 21c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70858391/146325).

Comment: @APC thanks - that looks really cool :) in my case I used a simpler alternative that required no string parsing.