# Is there a "diff" function in Oracle PL/SQL, that shows differences between two text strings?

Tags: oracle, plsql, diff

We have logging tables in our Oracle database that show old and new values when changes are made to certain data fields.  One of these fields is a SQL_TEXT field (for running reports via dynamic SQL).

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE schema1.rpt_sql_log (
   rpt_id  NUMBER(9),   -- surrogate key of report
   chg_id  NUMBER(9),   -- change number of query for this rpt_id
   old_sql_txt VARCHAR2(2000), -- old report SQL statement
   new_sql_txt VARCHAR2(2000)  -- new report SQL statement
);

INSERT INTO schema1.rpt_sql_log VALUES (
   1,
   2,
   'SELECT emp_id, dept_id, salary FROM emp ORDER BY emp_id',
   'SELECT emp_id, dept_nm, salary FROM emp e INNER JOIN dept d ON e.dept_id = d.dept_id ORDER BY emp_id'
);
COMMIT;
```

Our analyst ordinarily would export these fields to 2 separate text files and then open them in BeyondCompare, UltraCompare, or [WinMerge](https://winmerge.org/).  They have asked if it is possible to do this textual comparison/diff directly in a query (i.e., is there a built-in diff function).  To the best of my knowledge, no such built-in function exists.

My question is this: is there already a "diff-like" function available online that mimics the output of a [Myers diff algorithm](https://blog.jcoglan.com/2017/02/12/the-myers-diff-algorithm-part-1/) (i.e., something that highlights or <tag>s the changes, as one might see in Git or TortoiseSVN)

Comment: Well, just made it work using this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504832/highlight-differences-between-two-strings and the 21c release using the MultiLingual engine, e.g.: running JavaScript code inside the database. If you're interested, tell me and I can add the details as an answer.

Comment: @APC done, I did use Sean's introduction to MLE in 21c https://seanstacey.org/how-to-run-javascript-in-oracle-database-21c/2021/02/

Comment: Thank you, @loic, but we are using Oracle 12 and 19 databases,  We are not up to 21 yet.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, there is no such built-in PL/SQL function to do so.

However, using this [JavaScript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504832/highlight-differences-between-two-strings) which describes a diff function that adds  and  tags and the MultiLingual Engine capabilities of the [21c Oracle database release](https://hub.docker.com/r/gvenzl/oracle-xe) (which allows you to create stored procedures that can execute JavaScript code); you could go with such an approach:

```
set define off
set serveroutput on size unlimited

DECLARE
   ctx DBMS_MLE.context_handle_t := DBMS_MLE.create_context();
   codeSnippet clob ;
   result clob;
BEGIN
   codeSnippet := q'~
/*
 * Javascript Diff Algorithm
 *  By John Resig (http://ejohn.org/)
 *  Modified by Chu Alan "sprite"
 *
 * Released under the MIT license.
 *
 * More Info:
 *  http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/
 */

function escape(s) {
    var n = s;
    n = n.replace(/&/g, "&amp;");
    n = n.replace(/</g, "&lt;");
    n = n.replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    n = n.replace(/"/g, "&quot;");

    return n;
}

function diffString( o, n ) {
  o = o.replace(/\s+$/, '');
  n = n.replace(/\s+$/, '');

  var out = diff(o == "" ? [] : o.split(/\s+/), n == "" ? [] : n.split(/\s+/) );
  var str = "";

  var oSpace = o.match(/\s+/g);
  if (oSpace == null) {
    oSpace = ["\n"];
  } else {
    oSpace.push("\n");
  }
  var nSpace = n.match(/\s+/g);
  if (nSpace == null) {
    nSpace = ["\n"];
  } else {
    nSpace.push("\n");
  }

  if (out.n.length == 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < out.o.length; i++) {
        str += '<del>' + escape(out.o[i]) + oSpace[i] + "</del>";
      }
  } else {
    if (out.n[0].text == null) {
      for (n = 0; n < out.o.length && out.o[n].text == null; n++) {
        str += '<del>' + escape(out.o[n]) + oSpace[n] + "</del>";
      }
    }

    for ( var i = 0; i < out.n.length; i++ ) {
      if (out.n[i].text == null) {
        str += '<ins>' + escape(out.n[i]) + nSpace[i] + "</ins>";
      } else {
        var pre = "";

        for (n = out.n[i].row + 1; n < out.o.length && out.o[n].text == null; n++ ) {
          pre += '<del>' + escape(out.o[n]) + oSpace[n] + "</del>";
        }
        str += " " + out.n[i].text + nSpace[i] + pre;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return str;
}

function randomColor() {
    return "rgb(" + (Math.random() * 100) + "%, " + 
                    (Math.random() * 100) + "%, " + 
                    (Math.random() * 100) + "%)";
}
function diffString2( o, n ) {
  o = o.replace(/\s+$/, '');
  n = n.replace(/\s+$/, '');

  var out = diff(o == "" ? [] : o.split(/\s+/), n == "" ? [] : n.split(/\s+/) );

  var oSpace = o.match(/\s+/g);
  if (oSpace == null) {
    oSpace = ["\n"];
  } else {
    oSpace.push("\n");
  }
  var nSpace = n.match(/\s+/g);
  if (nSpace == null) {
    nSpace = ["\n"];
  } else {
    nSpace.push("\n");
  }

  var os = "";
  var colors = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < out.o.length; i++) {
      colors[i] = randomColor();

      if (out.o[i].text != null) {
          os += '<span style="background-color: ' +colors[i]+ '">' + 
                escape(out.o[i].text) + oSpace[i] + "</span>";
      } else {
          os += "<del>" + escape(out.o[i]) + oSpace[i] + "</del>";
      }
  }

  var ns = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < out.n.length; i++) {
      if (out.n[i].text != null) {
          ns += '<span style="background-color: ' +colors[out.n[i].row]+ '">' + 
                escape(out.n[i].text) + nSpace[i] + "</span>";
      } else {
          ns += "<ins>" + escape(out.n[i]) + nSpace[i] + "</ins>";
      }
  }

  return { o : os , n : ns };
}

function diff( o, n ) {
  var ns = new Object();
  var os = new Object();
  
  for ( var i = 0; i < n.length; i++ ) {
    if ( ns[ n[i] ] == null )
      ns[ n[i] ] = { rows: new Array(), o: null };
    ns[ n[i] ].rows.push( i );
  }
  
  for ( var i = 0; i < o.length; i++ ) {
    if ( os[ o[i] ] == null )
      os[ o[i] ] = { rows: new Array(), n: null };
    os[ o[i] ].rows.push( i );
  }
  
  for ( var i in ns ) {
    if ( ns[i].rows.length == 1 && typeof(os[i]) != "undefined" && os[i].rows.length == 1 ) {
      n[ ns[i].rows[0] ] = { text: n[ ns[i].rows[0] ], row: os[i].rows[0] };
      o[ os[i].rows[0] ] = { text: o[ os[i].rows[0] ], row: ns[i].rows[0] };
    }
  }
  
  for ( var i = 0; i < n.length - 1; i++ ) {
    if ( n[i].text != null && n[i+1].text == null && n[i].row + 1 < o.length && o[ n[i].row + 1 ].text == null && 
         n[i+1] == o[ n[i].row + 1 ] ) {
      n[i+1] = { text: n[i+1], row: n[i].row + 1 };
      o[n[i].row+1] = { text: o[n[i].row+1], row: i + 1 };
    }
  }
  
  for ( var i = n.length - 1; i > 0; i-- ) {
    if ( n[i].text != null && n[i-1].text == null && n[i].row > 0 && o[ n[i].row - 1 ].text == null && 
         n[i-1] == o[ n[i].row - 1 ] ) {
      n[i-1] = { text: n[i-1], row: n[i].row - 1 };
      o[n[i].row-1] = { text: o[n[i].row-1], row: i - 1 };
    }
  }
  
  return { o: o, n: n };
}

var bindings = require("mle-js-bindings");
var string1 = bindings.importValue("string1");   
var string2 = bindings.importValue("string2");   
bindings.exportValue("result", diffString(string1,string2)); ~';
   
dbms_mle.export_to_mle(ctx, 'string1', 'The red brown fox jumped over the rolling log.'); 
dbms_mle.export_to_mle(ctx, 'string2', 'The brown spotted fox leaped over the rolling log'); 

DBMS_MLE.eval(ctx, 'JAVASCRIPT', codeSnippet);
DBMS_MLE.import_from_mle(ctx, 'result', result); 

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(result);

DBMS_MLE.drop_context(ctx);

END;
/
```

Running the code above using SQLcl, gives me:

```
The <del>red </del> brown <ins>spotted </ins> fox <del>jumped </del><ins>leaped
</ins> over  the  rolling <del>log.
</del><ins>log
</ins>

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```